# How to sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n^2+2n+1)·(2·\ln(x))^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to sum: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n^2+2n+1)·(2·\ln(x))^n$$

I've tried considering $$S_N=1+4(2\ln(x))+9(2\ln(x))^2+...+(N^2+2N+1)(2\ln(x))^N$$
and $$(2\ln(x))·S_N=1(2\ln(x))+4(2\ln(x))^2+...+((N-1)^2+2(N-1)+1)(2\ln(x))^N+(N^2+2N+1)(2\ln(x))^{N+1}$$

So $S_N-(2\ln(x))S_N=1+3(2(ln(x))+5(2(ln(x))+...+$

But is this leading me to something? Is it the correct way to sum that?

Assume the series converges ($x\in(e^{-1/2},e^{1/2})$)

Comment: If you like, first let $y = 2 \log x$ and compute the power series, then plug it back. Seems that your method could work, if no calculation errors.

Comment: @xbh thanks. There would be a faster method? It's quite tedious doing it like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\ge0}(n^2+2n+1)y^n = \sum_{n\ge0}(n+2)(n+1)y^n-\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)y^n = \frac{2}{(1-y)^3}-\frac{1}{(1-y)}^2$$
Plug $y=2\ln x$ in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from $\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u^n$ you get

- $\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)u^n$
- $\Rightarrow \frac{d}{du}\left(u\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)\right) = \boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^2u^n}$ (This is your sum for $u =2 \ln x$.)
- Differentiating gives: 
  $$\frac{d}{du}\left(u\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)\right) = \frac{1+u}{(1-u)^3} \stackrel{|\ln x| < \frac{1}{2}}{\Rightarrow} \boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^2(2\ln x)^n = \frac{1+2\ln x}{(1-2\ln x)^3}}$$